# Ilist and Iqueryable

Tags: c#-4.0

this is the code i used in my application but i am confused with the need of a **ilist** interface over here and the use of **iqueryable**. what are they exactly defined for?

```
private IList<Emp2> getcountry()
        {
            IList<Emp2> countryList = null;
            using (CountryDataContext context = new CountryDataContext(ConnectionString))
            {
              IQueryable<Emp2> query = from c in context.Emp where c.EmpName=="ss"select c;
                countryList = query.ToList();
            }

            return countryList;
        }
```

Comment: i mean what are ilist and iqueryable??

Comment: Did you bother searching before asking here? The documentation on MSDN is extensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both interfaces.

Interfaces in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10197/The-Interface-Construct-in-C

msdn links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx

Comment: thanks sir. i know both are the interface but how can we use ilist as a method signature.. when to use this ilist and iqueryable interface?

Comment: You an use it as a signature so you can return a class/struct that implement from said interface. It helps to decouple the code form an implementation. You could have many classes that implement from IList, and use any of them as the return type. It is typical good programming in .Net to program to an interface so the code is less rigid.

Comment: Edited my original post due to accidentally using copy of MSDN link instead of CodeProject link to interface tutorial.